# will_paginate pagination links javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a simple jQuery script that plays/pauses video on hover that is working correctly when I first load the page, (e.g page 1) in rails with will_paginate gem.

My problem is that when I click to the next page or any other pages in particular, the jQuery script is not working but when I viewed the page source, the javascript code is still present.

I have to reload the page in order to get it to work?

```
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo);
//video is a div class that my videos use, this is at index.html.erb 
function hoverVideo(e) {
    $('video',this).get(0).play();
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video',this).get(0).pause();
}
```

Comment: post how you attach play/pause event

Comment: shown the script now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when your page is changed i believe the page refreshes with ajax and newly created elements have no events attached to them. The simplest solution is:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.video', hoverVideo ).on('mouseleave','.video',hideVideo );
```

This way jquery will always call `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` function but only fire your function when the element has specified class `.video`. So you don't worry anymore whether your newly created elements have any events attached to them or no

Comment: Hey thanks that worked! I'm fairly new to jquery and javascript in particular and I have trouble understanding why the newly created elements have no events attached to them?

Comment: Because previous element are literally **removed**, hence all the events attached to them vanish as well. When new elements appear on the page, your javascript has already fired before( page is not refreshed to fire it again ), meaning it won't attach events again, so you either have to do it manually, or like this, the latter is the simplest solution